# sharePoint 2010-installation -confusion

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have 2 WFE(2VM) server, 1 App Server(VM)  and Sql Server(VM), I am confused during the installation.

1. Which is best in farm configuration,

   - Create Farm in Application server and join the farm in WFE server?
   - or Create Farm in WFE and Join the farm in App Server?
2. Can we use the same install account in WFE and AppServer , actually here default login Administrator in these 2 servers. what permission we give sp-install account (admin,delegate permissions?
3. Where do we install SP-Designer s/w, Application server and or WFE server?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would start the installation in the Application Server and then make the WFE join the farm. An AS can live alone without a WFE, and you can configure AS related services and then add the WFE.
2. Yes, use a "setup account" for installing software, then specific accounts for the different services. You can even lock the setup account while not installing or upgrading, if you are very security concerned. The detailed rights that this setup account needs are quite complicated, [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662513%28v=office.14%29.aspx) from Microsoft Technet details the list of rights for SharePoint 2010.
3. SharePoint designer should be installed in the developer machine. If you need to forcibly use one of the servers, the WFE will be better.